# Xcode can't load image

Tags: xcode, macos

My new Macbook pro(OSX 10.9.1, Xcode 5.0.2) have a strange question. My Xcode can't load image like the below image. Is there are some people have the same question? how to fix? thanks![image]

Comment: Here I have the same problem... (Same OS X version, same Xcode version, iMac)

Answer (score 0):

Try including the images in an Asset Catalog (a .xcassets folder).  Here's how to [create an asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/CreatinganImageCatalog/CreatinganImageCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH2-SW1) and [add an image set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingImageSets/AddingImageSets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH3-SW1). Hope this helps!